# has a long shot vs is a long shot

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

Are these both correct?
**"He has a long shot at being the next president."
"He is a long shot at being the next president."**

Comment: Both are reasonably idiomatic.

Comment: It's not a shooting metaphor. It's a racing metaphor. A long shot is high odds, and it's the candidate who's the horse, so we say the candidate _is a long-shot_ the way we might say the candidate _is the favorite_.